# NA values in Rcpp conditional

Tags: r, rcpp

I am having trouble with conditionals in Rcpp.  The best way to explain my problem is through an example.

```
z <- seq(from=1,to=10,by=0.1)
z[c(5,10,15,20,40,50,80)] <- NA
src <- '
 Rcpp::NumericVector vecz(z);
 for (int i=0;i<vecz.size();i++) {
   if (vecz[i] == NA_REAL) {
     std::cout << "Here is  a missing value" << std::endl;
   }
  }
'
func <- cxxfunction(signature(z="numeric"),src,plugin="Rcpp")
func(z)
# NULL
```

From my understanding, `NA_REAL` represents the NA values for the reals in Rcpp and `NA_Integer` represents the NA values for integers. I'm not sure why the above conditional never returns true given `z`.

Comment: It's never true for basically the same reason that `NA == NA` is not true in R.

Comment: What is NA_REAL then? I got caught by this primarily because x==NA_INTEGER is used in the Rcpp sugar vignette, so I figured NA_REAL would work similarly.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You might want to use the R C level function **R_IsNA**.

```
require(Rcpp)
require(inline)
z <- seq(from=1, to=10, by=0.1)
z[c(5, 10, 15, 20, 40, 50, 80)] <- NA

src <- '
 Rcpp::NumericVector vecz(z);
 for (int i=0; i< vecz.size(); i++) {
   if (R_IsNA(vecz[i])) {
     Rcpp::Rcout << "missing value at position " << i + 1  << std::endl;
   }
  }
'

func <- cxxfunction(signature(z="numeric"), src, plugin="Rcpp")

## results
func(z)

missing value at position 5
missing value at position 10
missing value at position 15
missing value at position 20
missing value at position 40
missing value at position 50
missing value at position 80
NULL
```

Comment: Compare `NA` with `NA` gives `NA`. So `x[i] == x[i]` faster then `R_IsNA(x[i])`.

Comment: @ArtemKlevtsov I don't think you would want to use `x[i] == x[i]` since anything compared to 'NA' is 'NA'. The best R function is going to be `is.na(x)` because even something like `identical(x, NA)` does not always work (i.e. `identical(NA_integer_, NA)` returns `FALSE`).